# Error in accessing the right node pointer (Reference pointer) in tree

Tags: c++, struct, tree, doubly-linked-list, double-pointer

Doing a problem on how to convert a binary tree to a doubly linked list tree in the void po() function we are passing root node and 2 nodes as their address and now i want to set the right of one of the reference node i am doing the below way and getting error anyone know how to solve this ???

```
void po(Node* root,Node **p,Node**q){
        if(p==NULL)
            return;
        po(root->left,p,q);
        if(*p==NULL){
            *p=root;
            *q=root;
        }
        else{
            *(q)->right=root; // This line contain error !!!
            root->left=*q;
            *q=root;
        }
        po(root->right,p,q);
    }
    Node * bToDLL(Node *root)
    {
        if(root==NULL )
            return root;
        Node* a=NULL;
        Node* b=NULL;
        po(root,&a,&b);
        return a;
    }
```

Error :- error: request for member right in * q, which is of pointer type Node* (maybe you meant to use -> ?)
*(q)->right=root;
^

Comment: What is unclear with the error message?

Comment: Not able to access the right pointer of it

Comment: You probably wanted `(*q)->right`.

Comment: Yes Yksisarvinen but it showing error when i used this

Comment: Did you use that line as I wrote it? Your code has `*(q)->right`, which is equavalent to `*(q->right)`.

Comment: Ya i used this also but it still gives the error :- error: request for member right in * q, which is of pointer type Node* (maybe you meant to use -> ?)
         *(q->right)=root;

Comment: The correct version is `(*q)->right`. Your version (the wrong one) is `*(q)->right`, which is the same as if you wrote `*(q->right)` (again, wrong).

Comment: Thank you @Yksisarvinen my code work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
*(q)->right=root;
```

actually looks like

```
*(q->right) = root;
```

because the postfix operator -> has a higher precedence relative to the unary operator *.

But `q` is a pointer to pointer. So the pointed pointer does not have a data member `right`.

It seems you mean

```
( *q )->right = root;
```

In this case the expression `*q` points to an object of a structure type.